# what should we use to test existance

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In php symfony, we use doctrine.
In many part of our project we use the:

```
$entity = $manager->getRepository(Entity::class)->find(['toto' => $toto]);
```

or

```
$entity = $manager->getRepository(Entity::class)->findOneBy(['toto' => $toto]);
```

Then we test if we have some result. What is the best to do between:

```
if (!empty($entity )) {
some todo
}
```

and

```
if (null === $entity )) {
some todo
}
```

Comment: You must have a typo somewhere, since those two conditions are not equivalent.

Comment: find search for id, do you mean findBy?

Comment: Look at the method signatures: "return object|null The object". Testing for null is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way possibile for this scenario, at least to me, is to check for `instanceof` like

```
if ($entity instanceof Entity::class)
```

BTW this is really subjective but I would never prefer `empty` instead of `null` as them bring a totally different significance.

With `empty` the variable can possibly never been declared, it can be of different types (string, array, null, false) and so on.

With `null` and strict checking you are testing only for **that** (null) kind of value (and is fine untill doctrine changes its API which is not likely).

To use `instanceof` is the best to me as you "by-pass" all other values, whatever type you get back from the query.

Answer (score 1):

"If a variable simply doesn’t exist — usually because it hasn’t been declared, but sometimes because it hasn’t been assigned a value — it’s null. If the variable exists but contains no data, it’s empty. And if a structured data variable, such as an array, exists but doesn’t contain any items, it’s zero-length."
You can read the whole article here: https://www.dougv.com/2008/10/the-difference-between-null-empty-and-zero-length-data-strings/

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between find, findby and findoneby. findby return array, with one or more elements if it finds something, otherwise an empty array. findoneby returns the instance object of the entity class found, otherwise null.

For me you should test for find and findoneby

```
if ($entity instanceof Entity::class) { }
```

as suggested by @DonCallisto, while

```
if (count($entity) === 0) { }
```

if you use findby.

I also specified findby because find takes an id, findBy an array, and in your example I didn't understand what method you was referring to.

Comment: we use all 3 find, findby and findOneBy. The return either null/object, null/object/array, null/object.

Comment: findby should return only array @FlorentCardot, see https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.7/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.html#method_findBy